# Дерериализация json с неизвестными полями

Tags: c#, wpf, json, .net-core, datagrid

У меня есть json файлы которые нужно дерериализировать. Проблема в том что в них есть постоянные поля( есть во всех) и есть поля которые меняются(могут быть а могут и не быть).
Вот мой код:

```
Log MyLog = new Log();
      
        public  void json (string file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            { 
                MyLog = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Log>(File.ReadAllText(file));
            } 
        }

public class Log
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
        public string Exception { get; set; }
      
    }
```

И как потом мне в ДатаГрид WPF вывести все поля в таблице?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну если свойство есть, а в JSON его нет, то в результате вы получите пустое свойство (default), которое в DataGrid отобразиться как пустота. Можете пометить их все `nullable`, тогда если оно есть - будет значение, а если нету - null.

Comment: Не, так нельзя. Json имеет заранее известны формат, чтобы его дессериализовать. Если отличия только в +- пару полей, то отнаследуйте классы от базового, и в дессериализатор прокидывайте необходимый класс.

Comment: Покажите примеры ваших json

Comment: Если какой-то из ответов был полезен, пожалуйста, отметьте его принятым.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, но это звучит как ересь. "постоянные поля( есть во всех) и есть поля которые меняются".

На самом деле у вас всегда один класс Log с разными версиями. И если вы придерживаетесь принципов `SOLID` то у вас не должно возникнуть проблем с десериализацией. Если же нет то советую переделать так что ваш последний Log отвечал этим принципам, а точнее в данном случае `O - open closed`.  Ну и как частный случай это **Вариант 1. Обобщенный класс** предыдушего ответа